# What is the PostgreSQL equivalent for ISNULL()

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, null

In MS SQL-Server, I can do:

`SELECT ISNULL(Field,'Empty') from Table`

But in PostgreSQL I get a syntax error. How do I emulate the `ISNULL()` functionality ?

Comment: No you can't do that in MSSQL. That code will not compile. `ISNULL` takes two arguments and returns the second is the first is `null`, otherwise the first.

Comment: @GSerg, you are right. fixed that.

Comment: Gserg and Byron yes you can see here 
Example from my PC 

SELECT isnull( a.FechaEntregada ,'') as test
from dbo.Amonestacion a 

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx

Answer (score 540, accepted):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN field IS NULL THEN 'Empty' ELSE field END AS field_alias
```

Or more idiomatic:

```
SELECT coalesce(field, 'Empty') AS field_alias
```

Comment: +1 for `coalesce`. (P.S. You can do that in MS SQL Server, too.)

Comment: There are other cases for using IS NULL though, so it's good to know both.

Comment: I think it's worth noting that it is `coalesce` that is in SQL standard, with `isnull` being an MS-specific function that essentially is `coalesce` with only two parameters.

Comment: `COALESCE` is ANSI standard, and supported SQL Server 2000+

Comment: Coalesce() also handles type promotion properly (exactly like UNION SELECT does), while IsNull() does not.

Comment: Beware of doing operations on nullable values inside COALESCE, e.g. `COALESCE(my_table.nullable_column - my_table.cost_price, 0)`, as you may not get the coalesced zero value you expect.

Comment: It is worth pointing out that ISNULL and COALESCE are not the same. IsNull forces the result-type to the type of argument1, while coalesce uses the respective types for each argument. If you just search-and-replace isnull with coalesce, you can potentially get a lot of errors...

Answer (score 102):

Use `COALESCE()` instead:

```
SELECT COALESCE(Field,'Empty') from Table;
```

It functions much like `ISNULL`, although provides more functionality. Coalesce will return the first non null value in the list. Thus:

```
SELECT COALESCE(null, null, 5);
```

returns 5, while

```
SELECT COALESCE(null, 2, 5);
```

returns 2

Coalesce will take a large number of arguments. There is no documented maximum. I tested it will 100 arguments and it succeeded. This should be plenty for the vast majority of situations.

Answer (score 31):

> How do I emulate the ISNULL() functionality ?

```
SELECT (Field IS NULL) FROM ...
```

Comment: This emulates the exact functionality of isnull, not sure why it's downvoted

Comment: The best answer for the question, of course. This expression is the full equivalent of ISNULL(). COALESCE() is very smart and interesting to know but it cannot perform an ISNULL() while it is closed.

Comment: I don't know what `ISNULL` you commenters are referring to, but `field IS NULL` gives a boolean value, while `ISNULL` in SQL Server operates like `COALESCE`: it returns one of the non-`NULL` values. This answer is terribly wrong. See the documentation: [`ISNULL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx).

Comment: I suspect these commenters are MySQL users who didn't realize the question starts with, "In MS SQL Server, ..."  MySQL has an ISNULL() function that takes a single argument and returns 0 or 1.  T-SQL's version takes two arguments and behaves like COALESCE or Oracle's NVL.

Comment: The answer is wrong. Though it was explained in above comments, some people are still wondering why. Weird...

Comment: greatvovan, Whether or not this was the intent of the original poster, I believe what people are wanting is the answer to "How do I check if a field is null", not necessarily "How exactly does the ISNULL function work". That was the case with me and this answer is perfect for that.

Answer (score 22):

Try:

```
SELECT COALESCE(NULLIF(field, ''), another_field) FROM table_name
```

Comment: This is nice as it covers the case when a text field is NOT null, but also 'empty'.

Comment: This is a nice addition but confuses the original question by essentially tacking on "how do I coerce non-null fields to null?"