# Rails order by results count of has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Is there anyway I can order the results (`ASC`/`DESC`) by number of items returned from the child model (`Jobs`)?

```
@featured_companies = Company.joins(:jobs).group(Job.arel_table[:company_id]).order(Job.arel_table[:company_id].count).limit(10)
```

For example:  I need to print the Companies with highest jobs on top

Answer (score 53, accepted):

If you expect to use this query frequently, I suggest you to use built-in [counter_cache](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#controlling-caching)

```
# Job Model
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company, counter_cache: true
  # ...
end

# add a migration
add_column :company, :jobs_count, :integer, default: 0

# Company model
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :featured, order('jobs_count DESC')
  # ...
end
```

and then use it like

```
@featured_company = Company.featured
```

Comment: Well I really don't want to add extra column for this.

Comment: It depends. There is no perfect solution. If performance and clean code have priority, adding a column doesn't hurt at.

Comment: But then you have to update `companies.jobs_count` table for each insertion on the `jobs` table. That's 2 writes on 2 different tables. Where's the gain?

Comment: Very helpful, +1. AFAICS, there is only thing missing: if the DB has data, you'll start with a count=0 unless you do this: `Company.find_each { |company| Company.reset_counters(company.id, :jobs) }`.

Comment: This is by far the best answer, also see http://ryan.mcgeary.org/2016/02/05/proper-counter-cache-migrations-in-rails/ for information on writing a migration that allow for extremely quick updating of the counter_cache via SQL.

Answer (score 132):

## Rails 5+

Support for left outer joins was introduced in `Rails 5` so you can use an outer join instead of using `counter_cache` to do this. This way you'll still keep the records that have 0 relationships:

```
Company
  .left_joins(:jobs)
  .group(:id)
  .order('COUNT(jobs.id) DESC')
  .limit(10)
```

---

*The SQL equivalent of the query is this (got by calling `.to_sql` on it):*

```
SELECT "companies".* FROM "companies" LEFT OUTER JOIN "jobs" ON "jobs"."company_id" = "companies"."id" GROUP BY "company"."id" ORDER BY COUNT(jobs.id) DESC
```

Comment: this should be the really works answer, if you remove `.limit(10)`, you can get the companies have 0 jobs while other answers you will miss the 0 jobs companies.

Comment: I'm still using Rails 4. Can you show me the raw SQL for this?

Comment: This does not seem to work for associations. For example if a `SalesPerson` has many `Companies` as customers through deals. Then `sales_person.companies.left_joins(:jobs)...` would result in the database error "SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list".

Answer (score 28):

Something like:

```
Company.joins(:jobs).group("jobs.company_id").order("count(jobs.company_id) desc")
```

Comment: With this, if the object has 0 relationships it does disappear.

Comment: there's a gem left_join that can be used. But beware, nulls will appear first or last depending on the order direction. You can put 'em alwas last looking at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5826210/rails-order-with-nulls-last/7055259#7055259

Answer (score 28):

@user24359 the correct one should be:

```
Company.joins(:jobs).group("companies.id").order("count(companies.id) DESC")
```

Answer (score 6):

Added to Tan's answer. To include 0 association

```
Company.joins("left join jobs on jobs.company_id = companies.id").group("companies.id").order("count(companies.id) DESC")
```

by default, `joins` uses inner join. I tried to use `left join` to include 0 association

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the answers, the `direct raw SQL` was removed from rails 6, so you need to wrap up the SQL inside `Arel` (if the `raw SQL` is secure meaning by secure avoiding the use of user entry and in this way avoid the `SQL injection`).

`Arel.sql("count(companies.id) DESC")`

Answer (score -5):

```
Company.where("condition here...")
       .left_joins(:jobs)
       .group(:id)
       .order('COUNT(jobs.id) DESC')
       .limit(10)
```

Comment: This is a clear duplicate of my answer, you just added an extra `where` statement.