# Rails 3 complex query with sort

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a `User` model and an `Event` model.  User `has_many events`.  What I want to be able to do is find the User that has the most `events` created in the last 24 hours.

Ideally, the output format would have be an array of hashes `[{User => [Event, Event, ...]}]`, which would be sorted by User's with the highest `events.count`

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails order by results count of has\_many association](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16996618/rails-order-by-results-count-of-has-many-association)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me, but might require tweaking depending on your database.

```
class User
  scope :by_most_events, -> { 
    joins(:events)
    .select("users.*, count(events.id) as event_count")
    .where(events: { created_at: 24.hours.ago..Time.now })
    .group("users.id, events.id") # this is for postgres (required group for aggregate)
    .order("event_count desc")
  }
end

### usage

User.by_most_events.limit(1).first.event_count
# => 123
```

As Sixty4Bit mentioned, you should use `counter_cache`, but it will not suffice in this situation because you need to query for events *created in the last 24 hours*.