# Order parent model using children in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, models

I have model `product` and `vote`, I need to order products by votes count DESC.

product `has_many :votes`, vote `belongs_to :product`

**index_controller.rb**

```
def index
  @products = Product.all
end
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails order by results count of has\_many association](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16996618/rails-order-by-results-count-of-has-many-association)

Comment: I don't want extra column in DB

Comment: You may not want it, but you're going to be full-scanning the product table and joining to the foreign key for every row in the votes table without it. With an index on the counter cache column of the product table you'll get an index range scan on any decent relational database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@products = Product.order("count(votes) DESC")
```

If you have not votes column then use:

```
@products = Product.all.sort { |a, b| b.votes.count <=> a.votes.count   }
```

Comment: But how can i preform DESC sorting?

Comment: Just use Sort instead of Sort. I have updated my answer. look

Comment: Yeah, it is actually works, but can you say few words about how it works?