# How to order by integer returned by instance method?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, sqlite

I'd like to order a model query result by the sum of multiple `has_many` associations. For example, a `User` query method that orders results based on his/her total count of (comments + answers + votes). These are all models that belong to `User`.

I use a `User` instance method, `children`, to lump together these associations already, but I'm having trouble getting ActiveRecord's `order` method to order by `children.count`.

I want this to work (but it doesn't):

```
User.all.order("#{children.count} DESC")
```

How would one do this?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16996618/rails-order-by-results-count-of-has-many-association (The second-highest-rated answer is the correct solution for most.)