# Rails Select Most Popular Products

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to get a list of '10 most popular' products. I think that the best way to do this is to use `Orders` table (model) that has a reference to `Products`.

I know what I should do but I don't know how to write it. This is how I would do this in a MySQL:

```
SELECT  products.* 
FROM (SELECT product_id, count(product_id) as count from Orders 
           GROUP BY product_id
           ORDER BY count DESC
           LIMIT 10) AS O
LEFT OUTER JOIN products
ON Products.id  = O.product_id
```

How I can write the query in Rails?

For example: 
`Order.group(:product_id).count...`

Comment: query looks fine, if you change `left outer join` to `inner join`, it should just give you 10 products that meet the criteria. is that what you looking for?

Comment: @lusketeer I need it written in Rails... like: `Order.group(:product_id).count...`

Comment: Try `Products.joins(:orders).select("orders.product_id, count(orders.product_id) as count").order("count desc").group("orders.product_id")`

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16996618/rails-order-by-results-count-of-has-many-association

Comment: @ Amit Badheka Pykih Staff that's what I got:    `=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Product id: nil>, #<Product id: nil>, #<Product id: nil>, #<Product id: nil>, #<Product id: nil>]>`.     The query that run:      `SELECT orders.product_id, count(orders.product_id) as count 
FROM `products` 
INNER JOIN `orders` 
ON `orders`.`product_id` = `products`.`id` 
GROUP BY orders.product_id  ORDER BY count desc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
# One single query with join (extract the subquery and 
# assign it to an alias t using active_record function .from)
Product.joins("INNER JOIN t ON t.product_id = products.id")
       .from(
         Order
            .select("orders.product_id, COUNT(orders.id) as count")
            .group("orders.product_id").order("count DESC").limit(10), 
       :t)

# Alternative, but I think it will use 2 queries, 
# and the first one is probably faster
Product
      .where(id: 
      Order
         .select("orders.product_id, COUNT(orders.id) as count")
         .group("orders.product_id").order("count DESC").limit(10).pluck(:product_id))
```

### Update:

that code worked for me (@KazKazar):

`Product.joins("INNER JOIN products ON products.id = O.product_id")
        .from(Order.select("product_id, COUNT(product_id) as count")
        .group("product_id").order("count DESC").limit(10),:O)`

Comment: @KazKazar what's missing

Comment: not sure why wouldn't either one of them work, did you take out the spaces before running it? I put them on multiple lines to read better