# Rails active record query table by number of its associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have a `foo` table that has many `bar`s. How do I find all `foo`s that have more than 5 `bar`s? I was thinking something like `Foo.where(bar.length > 5)` but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Check

```
Foo.joins(:bars).group('foos.id').having('COUNT(bars.foo_id) > 5')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [counter_cache](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) first add this code and add new column

```
class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :Foo, counter_cache: true
  # ...
end

# add a migration
add_column :Foo, :bars_count, :integer, default: 0
```

then you can exec with

`Foo.where(:bars_count > 5)`

this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16996618/rails-order-by-results-count-of-has-many-association) maybe relevant