# [Rails][Postgres] How to order users by most posts in a category?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, polymorphic-associations, ransack

I am struggling to achieve this

I have 3 models,

- User (has_many :posts)
- Post (Belongs_to :user, HABTM :categories)
- Category (HABTM :posts)

Now, let's say I want to find and order all users who have submitted most posts in a category, how do I achieve this.

Eg. For category 'Fashion' I want to fetch & order users by number of user's posts in fashion.

Desired result should give,

- Mark (7 posts in fashion)
- Dave (5 posts in fashion)
- Carla (4 posts in fashion)
  .. so on

Note: Would prefer a solution that is compatible with postgres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I think the `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship for your purpose (or maybe almost any purposes) is inappropriate (or at least inconvenient) in this case.  You should use `has_many :through` instead.

Why?  Because `has_and_belongs_to_many` is not designed to achieve anything other than the bare-minimum basics, like what you want to do. For more in-depth justifications (of why you should use `has_many :through` for almost any many-to-many relationships), see, for example, "[Why You Don't Need Has_and_belongs_to_many Relationships](https://flatironschool.com/blog/why-you-dont-need-has-and-belongs-to-many)" by Flatiron School and
"[Create a many-to-many ActiveRecord association in Ruby on Rails with has_many :through and has_and_belongs_to_many](http://joshfrankel.me/blog/create-a-many-to-many-activerecord-association-in-ruby-on-rails/)" at Development Simplified. For your reference, "[Migration path from HABTM to has_many :through](http://www.chrisrolle.com/en/blog/migration-path-from-habtm-to-has_many-through)" by Christian Rolle may be helpful, which gives a migration guide for it.

Now, suppose you have migrated your model to "*has_many :through*". Then, in Rails 5+, which supports `left_joins`, (I think) the following will give the ordered User Relation based on the number of Posts each User has in a specified Category:

```rb
User.left_joins(:posts).
     left_joins(posts: :post_category_joins).
     where('post_category_joins.category_id = ?', YOUR_CHOSEN_CATEGORY_ID).
     group(:id).
     order('COUNT(post_category_joins.post_id) DESC')
```

where `post_category_joins` is your (chosen) join table name between Post and Category and `YOUR_CHOSEN_CATEGORY_ID` is the Category ID of your specified Category.

This answer is based on a Stackoverflow [answer to a has_many relationship case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42847464/3577922).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it certainly has pointed me to the right direction. I have made some progress, but still have not achieved the desired result. Please see this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/70638180/6752341