# How to order users by the number of user's posts in a particular category

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, associations, rails-activerecord, ransack

I have 3 models,

- User (has_many :posts)
- Post (Belongs_to :user, has_many :categories through: :posts_categories)
- Category (has_many :posts through: :posts_categories)

Now, I want to find **and order** all users who have submitted most posts in a category, **how do I achieve this using Ransack search**

Eg. For category 'Fashion' I want to fetch & order users by number of user's posts in fashion.

Desired result should give,

- Mark (7 posts in fashion)
- Dave (5 posts in fashion)
- Carla (4 posts in fashion) .. so on

Note: Would prefer a solution that is compatible with postgres

My ransack search in controller

```
@search = User.all.search(params[:q])
@searchusers = @search.result(distinct: true)

@findusers = @searchusers.joins(posts: :categories)
            .where(categories: { id: params['q']['posts_categories_id_eq'] })
            .group('users.id')
            .order('count(posts.id) desc').page(params[:page]).per(12)
```

Note: This works perfectly well in SQLite but fails in PG with below error
*'PG::Error: SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list'*

Comment: If you know the id of the category you don't actually have to join the categories table. You can simply count the rows in the `posts_categories` table with that id.

Comment: Hi.. can you please elaborate? Perhaps, with an example.

Comment: Also, the code I have shared works fine for SQLite but fails in Postgres with 'PG::Error: SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list'