# Move all nil dependent value using ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have two model Student and Information. Is this a order by nil?

```
Student | Information
Leo     | nil
Paul    | Some info1
Peter   | Some info2
Rex     | nil
```

How can I order it using active record and will show this result:

```
Student | Information
Paul    | Some info1
Peter   | Some info2
Rex     | nil
Leo     | nil
```

All nil Student.information.nil? will move down using ActiveRecord.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this topic can help you : [Rails: Order with nulls last](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5826210/rails-order-with-nulls-last)

```
Information.order('information_id IS NULL, information_id DESC')  # Null's last
Information.order('information_id IS NOT NULL, information_id DESC') # Null's first
```

If you are only using PostgreSQL, you can also do this

```
Information.order('information_id DESC NULLS LAST')  #Null's Last
Information.order('information_id DESC NULLS FIRST') #Null's First
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like :

```
Student.information.order('id DESC') # For having nil first
```

OR

```
Student.all.order('information_id DESC')
```

By default, when you order in Ascending order, all nil are pushed down. So for reverse effect use DESC.

This solution will work for all irrespective of underlying database.

Comment: Please let me know if it helped.