# MongoDB: Sorting by date treats null field as earlier date

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, sorting, mongoose

Mongoose schema includes this:

```
{
  dueDate: { type: Date, required: false }
}
```

My goal is to fetch docs sorted by dueDate with the soonest date at the top, followed by the rest with no dueDate. My problem is that a due date is not required therefore docs with no dueDate get sorted above docs with a valid date.

This is how I sort it (node.js & mongoose.js):

```
query.sort({ dueDate: 'asc' });
```

I'm mainly looking for a built in way to do this; I've already implemented a hack by combining queries.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order does this, if you want those values to appear at the bottom you will need to create a "max" value for the dates and init your documents with that max value as their default value.

Comment: Unfortunately there are other things that depend on the field being null. I may think about re-architecting so it doesn't though. Thanks for the input.

Comment: There has been thought about changing this so that only alphabetical sequences are effected by this, there is in fact JIRA ticket some where but I suck at searching, but yeah this is one of those "gotchas" about moving from SQL to MongoDB unforuntaterly :(

Answer (score 2):

Here is a workaround for date type which will require 1 additional field per such date field to be sorted (This solution can be used for numbers as well)

1. Store **negative epoch** of the non null dates (or -ve of number) in this new field.
2. Sort by date ascending would mean **sorting descending by this -ve epoch**. Nulls will be at the end as that is the way MongoDB sorts data in descending order. The actual date (or number) field will appear in ascending order, with nulls at end.
3. If there is need for nulls to be at and while sorting the date (or number) in descending order, sort on original date (or number) field instead of -ve epoch.

Answer (score 1):

there is no built in way to do that. There is a ticket opened to make helpers available to do customized sort functions, it is planned but not schedulled: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-153

Check this thread: [Is there a way to put all the nil value at the end when sorting with mongodb/mongoid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9201981/is-there-a-way-to-put-all-the-nil-value-at-the-end-when-sorting-with-mongodb-mon)

Regards,
Moacy