# Mongoid sorting NULL values to last + Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

We are using mongoid gem in our application. We have a set of records with `nil` values, for example, 
**`nil, nil, nil,3,4,1`**. 
We want to output like **`1,3,4,nil,nil,nil`**.

We are using pagination which uses `Mongoid::Criteria` object. Hence we cannot write two queries, then concat as it converts into an array and pagination needs `Mongoid::Criteria` object.

I tried with two queries with `nil` and not null, and then used the `merge` method to combine them, but it resulted in adding these two conditions, and resulted in zero records.

Is there any way using mongoid gem to push `nil` values to the end and not make `nil` values sorted in ascending order at the beginning?

Also

```
pipeline = [{"$match": {"_type": "Category"}},{"$project": {"sort_index": 1,"uri_id": 1, "nlt": { "$ifNull": [ "$sort_index", Time.now]}}},{"$sort": { "nlt": 1}}]

Category.collection.aggregate(pipeline)
```

This gives `Mongo::Collection::View::Aggregation`, but I need `Mongoid::Criteria` for pagination.

If we use partition this will return array object, but we need Mongoid::Criteria object

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to put all the nil value at the end when sorting with mongodb/mongoid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9201981/is-there-a-way-to-put-all-the-nil-value-at-the-end-when-sorting-with-mongodb-mon)

Comment: Here its using partition which will convert to the array. I need Mongoid::Criteria onject.

Comment: The Mongoid aggregation pipeline and simple queries (those that return `Mongoid::Criteria`) are two different things. Most likely the pagination gem you are using only supports `Mongoid::Criteria`. You might have to implement something yourself if you want to use pagination on aggregations if it does not exist out there.