# Why does PostgreSQL not return null values when the condition is <> true

Tags: sql, postgresql, null, comparison

I was confused behind the reasoning of the following:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE avalue is null
```

Returns x number of rows where 'avalue' is null

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE avalue <> true
```

Does **not** return rows where 'avalue' is null.

My reasoning (which appears to be incorrect) is that as `null` is a unique value (it isn't even equal to `null`) means that it should show in the result set as it isn't equal to `true` either.

I guess you could argue that by saying `column <> value` you imply that the column has a value therefore ignoring the `null` values altogether.

What is the reasoning behind this and is this the same in other common SQL DB's?

My reasoning (assumption) is telling me this is counter-intuitive and I wanted to learn why.

Comment: [Three-valued logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic). You're assuming that the only possible answers to `<>` are `true` or `false` - whereas in SQL, there is the option of `unknown`. This is in the standards. (Confusingly, MySQL conflates `UNKNOWN` and `NULL` so there, the possible results are `TRUE`, `FALSE` and `NULL`)

Comment: SQL Server does it in the same way.

Comment: As Damien is saying... This is commonly called three value logic.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE avalue is not true` should include which 'avalue' is null

Answer (score 34, accepted):

*Every* halfway decent RDBMS does it the same way, because it's **correct**. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparison.html)

> Ordinary comparison operators yield null (signifying "unknown"), not
> true or false, when either input is null. For example, `7 = NULL` yields
> null, as does `7 <> NULL`. When this behavior is not suitable, use the
> `IS [ NOT ] DISTINCT FROM` constructs:
>
> ```
> expression IS DISTINCT FROM expression
> expression IS NOT DISTINCT FROM expression
> ```

These expressions perform slightly slower than simple `expression <> expression` comparison.

For `boolean` values there is also the simpler `IS NOT [TRUE | FALSE]`.
To get what you expected in your second query, write:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE avalue IS NOT TRUE;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=49a9a43d41fce7f2a01da01ea0d8b047)*
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ff20b/1)</sub>

Comment: IMHO, this is flawed logic and not 'correct'. If I compare 7 to NULL, the answer should not be unknown, the answer should be false. This is SQL bending logic. Anyways, thanks for the great answer, the `IS DISTINCT FROM` saved the day.

Comment: @sandre89 The problem is that you cannot define an operator which combines or compares NULL (or "unknown") to anything else. What should be the result be for `7 > NULL` or `7 < NULL` or `7 + NULL`? Those operations do not make sense. Likewise `7 <> NULL` does not make sense, and the result is therefore unknown (which is represented as `NULL`).

Comment: @WizardofOgz I agree that 7 > NULL does not make sense. But 7 <> NULL is true and there's no way around it: it's different. The same way 7 = NULL should be false.

Comment: @sandre89: Except that's not true. `7 <> NULL` and `7 = NULL` are neither false nor true, but NULL.

Comment: "Because" is a very bad answer.

Comment: if `NULL` means `unknown`, `7 > NULL` should be NULL, same `7 < NULL, 7 <> NULL, 7 = NULL`. if `NULL` means `empty`, `7 = NULL, 7 > NULL, 7 < NULL`  should be `false`, `7 <> NULL` should be `true`

Answer (score 6):

[This link](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-and-the-snare-of-three-valued-logic/) provides a useful insight. Effectively as @Damien_The_Unbeliever points out, it uses Three-valued logic and seems to be (according to the article) the subject of debate.

A couple of other good links can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL#Null_and_three-valued_logic_.283VL.29) and [here](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/hugo_kornelis/archive/2007/07/17/the-logic-of-three-valued-logic.aspx).

I think it boils down to null not being a value, but a place holder for a value and a decision had to be made and this was it... so NULL is not equal to any value because it isn't a value and won't even not be equal to any value.... if that makes sense.

Comment: The article at simple-talk contains an error with the AND table. It states that "false AND unknown is unknown" when it should be "false AND unknown is false". Similarly with "unknown and false", it should be "false". This is discussed in the comments of the article but the article hasn't been updated.

Answer (score 2):

It is normal. SQL Server does it in the same way. In SQL Server you can use

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ISNULL(avalue, 0) <> 1
```

For postgresql equivalent watch this: [What is the PostgreSQL equivalent for ISNULL()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214525/what-is-the-postgresql-equivalent-for-isnull)

Consider to use NOT NULL column specification with default value, if it makes sense.

EDIT:

I think it is logic. NULL is not a value, so it is excluded from searching - you have to specify it explicitly. If SQL designers decides to go by second way (include nulls automatically), then you would get more troubles if you need to recognize no values