# Postgres not returning rows where value is NULL when !=

Tags: sql, postgresql

I see a thread here: [Why does PostgreSQL not return null values when the condition is <> true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17679721/why-does-postgresql-not-return-null-values-when-the-condition-is-true) with answers explaining *why* it happens but I'm still not sure how to fix it.

I'm running a query similar to this:

```
SELECT * FROM beers WHERE name != 'Budlight';
```

I expect it to return rows where `name` is not equal to `Budlight`. The results should include rows where name is `NULL`. Instead my results shows rows where `name` is not `Budlight` or `NULL`.

How can I form the query where only rows where name is not `Budlight` are ommitted from results?

SQLFiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/7b9bd/1

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Postgres offers the `is distinct from` operator.  You can do:

```
SELECT *
FROM beers
WHERE name IS DISTINCT FROM 'Budlight';
```

This does what you expect with `NULL` values.

This operator is explained in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-comparison.html).

Answer (score 4):

The SQL-standard way is just to say `OR col IS NULL`, e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM beers WHERE name <> 'Budlight' OR name IS NULL;
```

Gordon's answer points out `IS DISTINCT FROM` a non-sql-standard way of saying that. Note that PostgreSQL may not use indexes effectively for `IS DISTINCT FROM` so I tend to only use it in triggers comparing scalars, and use `col <> 'something' OR col IS NULL` the rest of the time.