# not like '%gmaii.co%' not working

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Im using SQL workbench connected to Redshift.

I wrote in my query EMail not like '%gmaii.co%' and for some reason NULLS are also being excluded.

Any idea on why its also excluding NULLS? I just want to exclude emails that have gmail.com.

Comment: If you are looking for gmail. Why does your SQL look for `gmaii`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Behaviour of NOT LIKE with NULL values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22818070/behaviour-of-not-like-with-null-values)

Comment: Useful resource https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17679721/why-does-postgresql-not-return-null-values-when-the-condition-is-true

Answer (score 3):

```
Select * from table
where Email not like '%gmaii.co%' or email is null
```