# How can you find rows where two values differ and one of them can be NULL? Why is NULL != 1 false?

Tags: sql, postgresql

In Postgres I want to find rows where one column is different than another. To my surprise, the comparison of 1 != NULL yields NULL which is a falsy value I guess and it is not included in the results.

```sql
SELECT * FROM (VALUES
  (0, 0),
  (0, 1),
  (1, 0),
  (1, 1),
  (0, NULL),
  (1, NULL),
  (NULL, 0),
  (NULL, 1),
  (NULL, NULL)
) v (x, y)
WHERE x != y
```

Results:

```
x   y
0   1
1   0
```

Here is online SQL fiddle to demonstrate the problem:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hTbJQJw36k3KrrJfUASpn9/0

I did find out, that when comparing anything with null, the result is always null and that is how [it's supposed to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17679721/why-does-postgresql-not-return-null-values-when-the-condition-is-true).

So I can get a bit closer when I ask for `WHERE x = y IS NOT TRUE`:

```sql
SELECT *, (x!=y) AS comp, (x=y IS NOT TRUE) AS not_true FROM (VALUES
  (0, 0),
  (0, 1),
  (1, 0),
  (1, 1),
  (0, NULL),
  (1, NULL),
  (NULL, 0),
  (NULL, 1),
  (NULL, NULL)
) v (x, y)
```

```
x     y     comp  not_true
0     0     false false
0     1     true  true
1     0     true  true
1     1     false false
0     null  null  true
1     null  null  true
null  0     null  true
null  1     null  true
null  null  null  true
```

I would want the last row to be true though. I understand that I am comparing anything with NULL and therefor getting NULL which is not TRUE, so yeah.

I can write an extra condition like `WHERE (x = y IS NOT TRUE AND (x IS NOT NULL OR y IS NOT NULL))`, but that seems overly complicated. Here is the updated SQL fiddle:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hTbJQJw36k3KrrJfUASpn9/1

Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `NULL` safe comparison operator:

```
where x is distinct from y
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=0e3cf37ea241e24d2392a48fb14bfbfa) is a db<>fiddle.

As to your "why" question.  `NULL` has well-defined semantics (meaning) in SQL.  It means that the value is *unknown*.  Hence, almost all comparisons returns `NULL` ("unknown").  The expression `1 <> NULL` evaluates to `NULL`, because `NULL` *could* be `1` -- or any other value.

The SQL Standard also implements functionality that handles this `is distinct from` and `is not distinct from`.  Postgres happens to be one of the few databases that actually implement this operator, but SQL does have appropriate comparison operators for equality to `NULL`.

Comment: Thanks! I did not know about "IS DISTINCT FROM". I found more on the subject here: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Is_distinct_from and here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparison.html