# SQL: How to merge two tables into one

Tags: postgresql

I have read solutions to merge two 3 row columns into one 6 row column but I think I want something else.

Let's say you have two columns:

```
Column 1      Column 2
NULL          D
B             NULL
C             NULL
```

Is there a way to get one table that has all the information?

```
Column 3
D
B
C
```

I'm getting these columns after doing UNION ALL. So these are not the 
database tables but the columns that I have selected.

I'm using postgresql.

This is what I tried so far:

```
SELECT col1, col2, t2.col3 from t1
LEFT JOIN t2
ON t1.col1 like  '%.'||t2.col3

UNION ALL

SELECT col1, col2, col3 From t1
LEFT JOIN t2
ON t1.col1 = concat(t2.col3, '.')
```

You can see that as I'm joining the same two tables on different conditions, I am getting different pieces of information.

Comment: Could you use code tags please? It gets confusing telling which Columns your talking about, is that a `D` column or a `DB` column? `Column 3 D` `B C` or `Column 3 D B C` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the PostgreSQL equivalent for ISNULL()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214525/what-is-the-postgresql-equivalent-for-isnull)

Answer (score 3):

The function you're looking for is [`COALESCE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-conditional.html)

```
SELECT COALESCE(Column1,Column2) AS Column3 
FROM t1
```

The way you were trying to do it was super-complicated, you could have probably also solved it like

```
SELECT Column1 FROM t1 WHERE Column1 IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT Column2 FROM t1 WHERE Column2 IS NOT NULL
```

I'd stick with the first way