# Select max + 1 else 1

Tags: sql, postgresql

Below is my table book.

```
        ID  BookName StoreId  Sequence Price
        1    ABC       1         1      450
        2    DEF       1         2      450
        3    GHF       2         1      300
```

So above table is book table, Each store will have multiple books. I am writing a function which will insert book record in this table. While inserting the new record our requirement is new book sequence should `Max(Sequence) + 1` of corresponding store. I have written below query for that.

```
    INSERT INTO Book(BookName,StoreId,Sequence,Price) Values
       (@name,@sid,(SELECT MAX(Sequence) + 1 from book where StoreId=@StoreId),@price)
```

This query is working fine when we already have inserted `storeId` present in table but as soon as i give `storeId` not present table Sequence will come as `NULL` because we don't have any existing sequence for that store and `Max(sequence)+1` will give `Null`. What is best way to resolve this?

Comment: On a side note, you have to `LOCK TABLE Book IN EXCLUSIVE MODE` before you do this, otherwise you can insert duplicate IDs from concurrent transactions. I strongly suggest using a counter table based approach instead; search for "postgresql gapless sequence" to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

Try It :

```
INSERT INTO Book
       (BookName,StoreId,Sequence,Price)
Values
       (@name,@sid,(SELECT MAX(Sequence) + 1 from book),@price)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use some sort of isnull function or coalesce.

**refer this.**

[What is the PostgreSQL equivalent for ISNULL()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214525/what-is-the-postgresql-equivalent-for-isnull)

```
INSERT INTO Book(BookName,StoreId,Sequence,Price) Values
       (@name,@sid,coalesce((SELECT MAX(Sequence) + 1 from book where StoreId=@StoreId),1),@price)
```