# how to handle isnull() in Dbeaver

Tags: sql, dbeaver

isnull() is not functioning in Dbeaver 21.1.0 .
Do you have any suggestions how can I include this function?

Comment: `COALESCE()` is ANSI Standard. You should look.

Comment: This should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214525/what-is-the-postgresql-equivalent-for-isnull

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Hi. I'm using AWS database