# AWS Redshift SQL equivalent of Tableau

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, tableau-api

I have this code in tableau which I need to convert to Redshift SQL

```
(
zn(
 sum([Market_Price])
  )-
zn(
 sum(
   if ISNULL([Market_Price]) then null else [Initial_Price] end
    )
))/
zn(sum([Market_Price]))
```

I have tried but not getting the same results.
Do we have isnull and zn equivalent in Redshift?

Comment: AWS has ~10 different services/DBs that support SQL. Which you are using and what you have already attempted is relevant.

Comment: I am using Redshift

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2214525/1032785

Comment: what about zn()

Answer (score 2):

You can replace zn(X) with nvl(X,0)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
select (
  coalesce(sum("Market_Price"),0) -
  coalesce(sum(case when "Market_Price" is null then null else "Initial_Price" end ),0) 
        ) / sum("Market_Price")
from your_redshift_table
;
```