# Postgresql equivalent of SQL Server query

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I am migrating database from SQL Server to Postgresql and I am currently stuck at converting this query. I have referred to the documentation but I don't seem to find any solution.

Here is the query (undeclared `@variables` are .NET variables):

```
declare @table_name as varchar(64) 
set @table_name = (select tbl_name from tbl1 where id = @id)

if @table_name = 'xyz' 
begin
    exec('select col1, col2, col3, col4 from '+@table_name+' where condition1='+@vbl1+' and condition2='+@vbl2+' and condition3=''abc'' and condition4='''+@vbl4+'''
          union all
          select col1, col2, col3, col4 from '+@table_name+' where condition1='+@vbl1+' and isnull(col3,''0'')=''0'' and condition3=''abc'' and condition4='''+@vbl4+'''
         ')
end
else
begin
    exec('select col1, col2, col3, col4 from '+@table_name+' where condition1='+@vbl1+' and condition2='+@vbl2+' and condition3=''abc''
          union all
          select col1, col2, col3, col4 from '+@table_name+' where condition1='+@vbl1+' and isnull(col3,''0'')=''0'' and condition3=''abc''
         ')
end
```

I tried to convert this and here is what I could do:

```
create function ufn_function1(V_tbl_name anyelement, V_id integer, vbl1 integer, vbl2 integer, vbl4 integer) returns setof anyelement as $$
declare
V_table_name varchar:=(select V_tbl_name from tbl1 where id=V_id);
begin
if V_table_name= 'xyz'
then
return query execute format('
select col1, col2, col3, col4 from '||V_table_name||' where condition1='||vbl1||' and condition2='||vbl2||' and condition3=''abc'' and condition4='''||vbl4||'''
union all
select col1, col2, col3, col4 from '||V_table_name||' where condition1='||vbl1||' and isnull(col3,''0'')=''0'' and condition3=''abc'' and condition4='''||vbl4||'''
  ');
else
return query execute format(' 
select col1, col2, col3, col4 from '||V_table_name||' where condition1='||vbl1||' and condition2='||vbl2||' and condition3=''abc''
union all
select col1, col2, col3, col4 from '||V_table_name||' where condition1='||vbl1||' and isnull(col3,''0'')=''0'' and condition3=''abc''
 ');
end if;
end;
$$ language 'plpgsql';
```

Obviously this is not the correct conversion and has multiple syntax errors as I am completely alien to Postgresql.

Any help in converting this query is highly appreciated.

Comment: As a note, in T-SQL, that query is awfully open to injection. *If* someone does translate this, it should not be open to the same significant security risks.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do with "anyelement" there. What sort of values are you hoping to accept in `v_tbl_name`? Actually, it doesn't look like you intended to use it either.

Comment: Don't use string concatenation when you're already using `format`! Use interpolation with the correct escaping modifiers.

Comment: Have you considered converting the logic to a .NET function? Building the query there might be much easier, depending on the db library you're using.

Answer (score 1):

You really need to rethink your approach.

Generally, plain SQL does not allow interpolation / parameterization for identifiers (table or columns names etc.). You need to concatenate the query string, and then execute it. In PL/pgSQL, you can do this kind of **"dynamic SQL"** with `EXECUTE`. The function `format()` is instrumental in concatenating the string safely.

But the **return type of a function** cannot be completely dynamic. There are limited workarounds. Like returning anonymous records (which I don't find very useful). Or a polymorphic functions. See:

- [Refactor a PL/pgSQL function to return the output of various SELECT queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740256/refactor-a-pl-pgsql-function-to-return-the-output-of-various-select-queries/11751557#11751557)

But that requires you to pass the return type with the call, which is not possible with your workflow, where you only pass an ID to fetch a table name. Plus, your original code seems inefficient and open to SQL injecton.
However, your return type *looks* constant after all. If so, this could work:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ufn_function1(_id int, _vbl1 int, _vbl2 int, _vbl4 int)
  -- OUT columns must match result!
  -- Falling back to text while undisclosed
  RETURNS TABLE (col1 text, col2 text, col3 text, col4 text)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   -- the cast to regclass raises an exception immediately
   -- if tbl1.tbl_name is not a valid table name (or null)
    _tbl regclass := (SELECT tbl_name::regclass FROM tbl1 WHERE id = _id);
BEGIN
   IF _table_name IS NULL THEN     -- no table name, no go
      RAISE WARNING 'No table name found!';

   ELSIF _table_name = 'xyz' THEN  -- constant table name, plain SQL
      RETURN QUERY
      -- casting result columns to text while actual types are undisclosed
      SELECT t.col1::text, t.col2::text, t.col3::text, t.col4::text  
      FROM   xyz t
      WHERE  t.condition1 = _vbl1
      AND    t.condition2 = _vbl2
      AND    t.condition4 = _vbl4
      AND   (t.condition3 = 'abc' OR t.col3 <> '0' IS NOT TRUE);

   ELSE   -- dynamic table name, dynamic SQL
      RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format(
         $q$
         SELECT t.col1::text, t.col2::text, t.col3::text, t.col4::text
         FROM   %I t
         WHERE  t.condition1 = $1
         AND    t.condition2 = $2
         AND    t.condition4 = $3
         AND   (t.condition3 = 'abc' OR t.col3 <> '0' IS NOT TRUE)
         $q$, _table_name)
      USING _vbl1  -- $1
          , _vbl2  -- $2
          , _vbl4  -- $3
      ;
   END IF;
END;
$func$;
```

There are subtle details to this. Too much for a single question.
Start by learning [PL/pgSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html).

Related:

- [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter/10711349#10711349)
- [Best way to check for "empty or null value"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23766084/best-way-to-check-for-empty-or-null-value/23767625#23767625)
- [What is the PostgreSQL equivalent for ISNULL()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214525/what-is-the-postgresql-equivalent-for-isnull)